# I'm trying to get some tweets with academictwitteR, but the code points to an error with endpoint_url

Tags: r, http-status-code-403, bearer-token, tweets

I'm trying to get some tweets with `academictwitteR`, but the code throws the following error:

```
    tweets_espn <- get_all_tweets( query = "fluminense",
+                                   user = "ESPNBrasil",
+                                   start_tweets  =  "2020-01-01T00: 00: 00Z " ,
+                                   end_tweets  =  "2020-31-12T00 : 00: 00Z " ,
+                                   n = 10000)
```

> query:  fluminense (from:ESPNBrasil)  Error in make_query(url =
> endpoint_url, params = params, bearer_token = bearer_token,  :
> something went wrong. Status code: 403 In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: Recommended to specify a data path in order to mitigate data loss
> when ingesting large amounts of data.  2: Tweets will not be stored as
> JSONs or as a .rds file and will only be available in local memory if
> assigned to an object.

Answer (score 1):

it seems to me that you can only access the Twitter API via academictwitteR if you have been awarded the "academic research" access from the Twitter developer portal. So i dont think it works with the essential or elevated access.

Comment: But the OP clearly states that they _are_ using academictwitteR, so this shouldn’t apply to them, right?